# IF in combination with VLOOKUP returns in #VALUE

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm working with an Excel sheet that has 2 sheets.
Sheet 1 has all the data with the key in Column 1 and answer/data in Column 3.

There are a lot of rows and this is changing continuously, so one would make this maintenance free.

If a certain row in Sheet 1 has an empty value, sheet 2 will show a '0'.
To prevent this from happening, I created the following formula with example information.

Sheet 1 starts on A3 and ends on A300 (answers in column 3 aka C)
Record in sheet 1 with empty cell is A10

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A10;'Sheet1'!$A$3:$C$300;3;TRUE);VLOOKUP(A10;'Sheet1'!$A$3:$C$300;3;TRUE);"")
```

So if value of A10 in Sheet 1 in Column 3 = TRUE, get that value and present it else show nothing.
This works flawlessly, however, when I update the cell in Sheet1 in C10, with Yes. The VLOOKUP in Sheet2 will return #VALUE.
Once I update the value in C10 with random numeric values such as 123456, Sheet2 will show 123456.

Once I remove the IF statement around VLOOKUP the value of Sheet2 will becomes Yes (after I updated Sheet1 C10 back to Yes).

Anyone know if IF(VLOOKUP) works on Text? In my situation it doesn't somehow, but with numbers its fine.

With kind regards,
Engineer

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$A$3:$A$300;A10)>0;VLOOKUP(A10;'Sheet1'!$A$3:$C$300;3;TRUE);"")`.

Comment: Hi BigBen, your code works partially, it does return Text now, however when the cell is emptied, Im seeing the '0' again in the VLOOKUP cell. Why would that be even after we configured it should be left empty with the FALSE statement "" ?

Comment: `COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$A$3:$A$300;A10)>0` just checks whether `A10` is found in Sheet1. It doesn't check whether the result of the `VLOOKUP` is 0 or not.

Comment: Exactly, so in my case C10 was filled with Yes, so the Countifs found a value which is bigger than 0 right? So it presented 'Yes' as return value. Once I removed the 'Yes' in C10 the VLookup returns with '0' which is odd because we told the formula to return empty string and not a '0'.

Comment: Not odd. `COUNTIFS` doesn't look at column C, it looks at column A. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the logic a bit:

- Check if `A10` can be found on sheet 1 (can be done many different ways, I've chosen `COUNTIFS`).
- If found, check that the `VLOOKUP` does not return 0.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A3:A300;A10)>0;IF(VLOOKUP(A10;Sheet1!A3:C300;3;TRUE)<>0;VLOOKUP(A10;Sheet1!A3:C300;3;TRUE);"");"")
```